# Type check Pydantic BaseModel as type hint with mypy

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy, pydantic, typechecking

I am using pydantic to create models and apply data validation. Simultaneously I'd like to use these models as type hints (because they contain more information than simply saying `dict`). Killing two birds with one stone :)

```python
from pydantic import BaseModel, StrictStr, StrictInt

class Person(BaseModel):
    name: StrictStr
    age: StrictInt


def my_func(user: Person) -> None:
    print(user["name"])
```

However, mypy does not properly parse the models, and gives this error message:
`error: Value of type "Person" is not indexable  [index]`

I'd like mypy to type check the pydantic BaseModel and not give an error.

Optionally I could create a TypedDict and use that as type hint, but then I lose the pydantic strict functionality.

Comment: Have you actually tried to run this code example? What makes you think you can subscript Pydantic models (use `[]`-notation)? This is not a type checking issue, it is just that you are attempting to call the `__getitem__` method, which the model does not implement.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "loosing Pydantic strict functionality", if you use a `TypedDict`? Could you give an example of the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the short answer is that you don't get to use the `[]` operator on instances of a class derived from the Pydantic `BaseModel`.

Since you created the class you can simply get the `Person`'s name with `person.name`, so your function would look like this:

```py
 def my_func(user: Person) -> None:
    print(user.name)
```

---

If you *need* to use your `Person` instance as a `dict` you can do it, and there are two methods.

1. pass the person instance to the `dict` constructor like `dict(person)`
2. you can call the `.dict()` method of the person instance like: `person.dict()` This will allow you to do a "partial" class even.

To learn more check out the [docs](https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/exporting_models/)

---

Since you use `mypy` and seem to be a beginner with Pydantic I'm guessing you don't have the `mypy` plugin for Pydantic set up. You don't need to install anything, as it comes with the Pydantic package.

If you use a `pyproject.toml` file (and I believe you should), you add this to the end to enable it.

```
[tool.mypy]
plugins = [
  "pydantic.mypy"
]
```

To learn more about the plugin, you can take a look at its [docs](https://docs.pydantic.dev/mypy_plugin/)